# missing required architecture x86_64 -core plot

Tags: core-plot, xcode5

I put core-plot 1.4 header into my project, add library, add quartz-core, accelerate, -ObjC on linker flag but If I try to compile I get this error:
[image]

Comment: Is this a Mac app? If so, use the Core Plot framework, not the iOS static library.

Comment: no is iPhone app, I find the problem, i think core-plot not support 64-bit, if I remove 64 bit as architecture it works!

Comment: Since February 2015 Apple requires 64-bit architecture support (not simply running on 64 bit devices/iOS). So reopen question please

Answer (score 6, accepted):

64-bit builds require iOS 7. Since Core Plot still supports earlier iOS versions we cannot turn on 64-bit by default. However, if you build the Core Plot library from source, you can change the project settings to build a 64-bit version. Either make Core Plot a dependent project inside your app, or build the "Universal Library" target to make a new static library.

Comment: thank you, the app is a database app based, so I don't need a lot of resource, is a problem if I set architecture without 64 bit?

Comment: No, it will still run on 64-bit devices. You just won't get the performance benefits from the new architecture.

Answer (score 1):

1. Do general set up for supporting 64 bit in Project --> Build settings.
2. Download the libCoreplot-CorePloat.a static library here:

"https://www.dropbox.com/s/023f0bjrbjo855m/libCorePlot-CocoaTouch.a%202?dl=0"

It supports i368 , arm64 , armv7 and armv7s.